# How to interpret QQ plot with two datasets

Tags: r, data-visualization

About QQ-plot, for one dataset, the x-axis shows theoretical quantile and y-axis shows sample quantile. So the more points gather on the y = x line, I can think that the more sample quantiles are equal to the theoretical quantiles. Then I can conclude the sample distribution is similar to the theoretical distribution shown in the x-axis.

My question is: when there are two datasets, `qqplot(x,y)` gives the plot with quantile of x in x-axis and quantile of y in y-axis. Follow the previous idea, the more points on the y = x line, the more chance I can conclude that x and y have the same distribution. But how do I conclude that they are from the bivariate normal distribution?

And if there are more than two datasets, how can I prove whether all of them from the same distribution? (Divide them into two by two pairs and draw the qqplot?)

Comment: Can you please show some code of what you tried already ?

Comment: qqplot(as.numeric(MSFT.ret), as.numeric(AAPL.ret), xlab="AAPL",     ylab="MSFT", main = "Log-return QQ-plot")
abline(a = 0, b = 1, col="maroon3"), like this, qqplot with two dataset. How to interpret this qqplot and why?

Comment: Can you please edit your post with the new information? New information should be in edits not in comments!